# Issue with String unicode

Tags: java, string, unicode

I am facing issues while comparing two strings. It always results in false. I think there is an issue with unicode of space.

```
String actual =   "cars in";
String expected = "cars in";
for(int i=0;i<expected.length();i++){
        System.out.print(expected.codePointAt(i)+" ");
        System.out.print(actual.codePointAt(i)+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
if(actual.equals(expected)){
        System.out.println(true);
    }else
        System.out.println(false);
```

I've tried printing the codePoint also, which gives following result.

```
99 99 
97 97 
114 114 
115 115 
32 160 
105 105 
110 110
```

so the value of space differs, in first string the value is `32` and in second string the value is coming as `160` due to this it is giving false everytime I compare the two.

How do i fix this issue?

Comment: '160' is a *non-breaking space* when 32 is just a *space* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: so how do I compare the string that I get a true result.

Comment: you can use `String replace()` to convert non-breaking spaces into prdinary spaces

Answer (score -1):

you can try spilitting the string on the basis of space -:

```
String actual = "cars in";
String expected = "cars in";
String[] str1 = actual.split(" ");
String[] str2 = expected.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    if (str1[i].equals(str2[i])) {
        System.out.println(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: this may have changed because I copy pasted the code here.. in my machine the output is the same that I've given.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. You can always [edit] your post to change it into actual answer.